# How to show a local image in an interactive dash with python

Tags: python, html, plotly-dash

So I am working on Dash Plotly. The webpage should have a text box and a button. The idea is that when I write an image name and then select the button, it will show the image from a local directory.

I tried to divide the whole  work into 2 parts.

First, I have this code which shows you whatever you write in the text box and click the button. The code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import os 
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

external_stylesheets = ["https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css"]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.I("Try typing the image name in input and observe it"),
        html.Br(),
        dcc.Input(id="input", type="text", placeholder=""),
        html.Div(id="output"),
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    Output("output", "children"),
    Input("input", "value")
)
def update_output(input):
    return u'Input {}'.format(input)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Next, I have this code which when run locally, just shows you the image in the webpage. Point: the python file and the image are in same local directory. The code:

```
import os 

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

# Change working dir to current running script dir:
print('[change directory]')
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

def test():
    # load the image
    img = np.array(Image.open('img name.tiff'))

    fig = px.imshow(img, color_continuous_scale='gray')
    fig.update_layout(coloraxis_showscale=False)
    fig.update_xaxes(showticklabels=False)
    fig.update_yaxes(showticklabels=False)
    fig.show()

test()
```

Now, I need a way to add these 2 codes so that when I write 'img name.tiff' in the text box and select the button, it will show me the picture in the webpage.

I am very new in Dash and Plotly. I have no idea how to do it. I tried to study it but could not find anything helpful. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could change your callback to something like this:

```
@app.callback(Output("output", "children"), Input("input", "value"))
def update_output(input):
    if not input:
        raise PreventUpdate

    try:
        img = np.array(Image.open(f"assets/{input}"))
    except OSError:
        raise PreventUpdate

    fig = px.imshow(img, color_continuous_scale="gray")
    fig.update_layout(coloraxis_showscale=False)
    fig.update_xaxes(showticklabels=False)
    fig.update_yaxes(showticklabels=False)

    return dcc.Graph(figure=fig)
```

If there's no input value or the image with the user specified path can't be opened, we use [`PreventUpdate`](https://dash.plotly.com/advanced-callbacks):

> In certain situations, you don't want to update the callback output. You can achieve this by raising a PreventUpdate exception in the callback function.

*Note: this example assumes the image is stored in the `assets` folder.*

**Update: Implementation using button**

```
@app.callback(
    Output("output", "children"),
    Input("input", "value"),
    Input("show-image", "n_clicks"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def update_output(input, n_clicks):
    if not input:
        raise PreventUpdate

    ctx = dash.callback_context
    if ctx.triggered[0]["prop_id"].split(".")[0] != "show-image":
        raise PreventUpdate

    try:
        img = np.array(Image.open(f"assets/{input}"))
    except OSError:
        raise PreventUpdate

    fig = px.imshow(img, color_continuous_scale="gray")
    fig.update_layout(coloraxis_showscale=False)
    fig.update_xaxes(showticklabels=False)
    fig.update_yaxes(showticklabels=False)

    return dcc.Graph(figure=fig)
```

In the previous example on finding an image that can be opened the callback returns the graph with the image. If you want to defer showing the image until a button is clicked you can add a button to the layout

```
html.Button("Show Image", id="show-image", n_clicks=0)
```

and use `callback_context` to determine which `Input` triggered the button. If the `id` of this input equals `"show-input"` (the `id` of our button) we show the graph and image.

Comment: Hey, the solution is almost perfect, just a small issue. When I run it there is this textbox where I can write the name of the image. Then when I select the left mouse button (not Enter), it shows me the image. But there is no Button where I can click to show the image.  Can you check it?

Comment: @KhabbabZakaria The first callback actually shows the graph the moment you type in a name of an image that exists and can be opened, irrespective of a left mouse or enter click. See the second example in my updated answer for a callback that defers loading the image until after a button is clicked.